# ApplicationRunner VS CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot and read about the **ApplicationRunner** and **CommandLineRunner**. Both are functioning same. When I implement both interfaces at the same time, always **CommandLineRunner's** method runs first then **ApplicationRunner's** method.

Anyone can help, why **CommandLineRunner's** method getting preference over **ApplicationRunner's** method.

Comment: What behavior do you expect?  How can one not run before the other?

Comment: Curiously, just I want to know this behavior

Answer (score 5):

Here's a real answer to your question, obtained by looking at the Spring code.  All runners are run by the main thread at the end of startup, via this method:

```
private void callRunners(ApplicationContext context, ApplicationArguments args) {
    List<Object> runners = new ArrayList<>();
    runners.addAll(context.getBeansOfType(ApplicationRunner.class).values());
    runners.addAll(context.getBeansOfType(CommandLineRunner.class).values());
    AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(runners);
    for (Object runner : new LinkedHashSet<>(runners)) {
        if (runner instanceof ApplicationRunner) {
            callRunner((ApplicationRunner) runner, args);
        }
        if (runner instanceof CommandLineRunner) {
            callRunner((CommandLineRunner) runner, args);
        }
    }
}
```

It sounded to me like what you were doing was implementing both runner interfaces on the same object.  When you do that, the above code shows that the `ApplicationRunner` method is run first, and then the `CommandLineRunner` method.  But you seem to say that you see the opposite behavior.  I implemented a single class that implemented both runners, and I saw the two methods executed in the order I expected per the above code.

So you must be implementing these interfaces in two different classes. In that case, the order is determined by how the `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort` method chooses to order your two runner classes, because this method is used, per the above code, to sort the list of all runners to determine the order in which they are called.

The description of the `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator` is:

> AnnotationAwareOrderComparator is an extension of OrderComparator that supports Spring's Ordered interface as well as the @Order and @Priority annotations, with an order value provided by an Ordered instance overriding a statically defined annotation value (if any).

And the sort method's description is:

> Sort the given list with a default AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.

So apparently, if you wanted to force a particular order of execution of your runners, you could use @order or @Priority annotations to accomplish that.

So there you have it.  If you need more detail than this, you'll need to dig into the details of how the `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator` chooses how to order your two classes.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't think it's needed in any case to implement both of these interfaces at the same time.

Both, when implemented, indicate that the `run` method should be invoked at the application startup.

The difference between `ApplicationRunner` and `CommandLineRunner` is that, on `ApplicationRunner`, instead of raw string arguments passed to the `run` method, we have an instance of `ApplicationArguments` so that you can access the bootstrap arguments passed when initializing the application.

With `CommandLineRunner` you can access them as well, but as raw string arguments, so you'll have to parse them yourself.

You could test it yourself:

Running the application with the argument `--my-config=xyz` will provide the bellow result when implementing `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner`:

Using `CommandLineRunner`:

```
@Component
public class CLIRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Arguments passed when bootstraping the app: " + Arrays.asList(args));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Arguments passed when bootstraping the app: [--my-config=xyz]
```

Using `ApplicationRunner`:

```
@Component
public class AppRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Arguments passed when bootstraping the app: " + args.getOptionNames());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Arguments passed when bootstraping the app: [my-config]
```

As you saw, both of them provide, almost, the same functionality. I would suggest always to use `ApplicationRunner`, because then you don't have to parse the arguments yourself, since Spring already did and made it available to you within the `ApplicationArguments` object.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between CommandLineRunner and ApplicationRunner is that the run() method of CommandLineRunner accepts array of String as an argument and run() method of ApplicationRunner accepts spring ApplicationArguments as an argument.

To execute them in an order, you can use spring @Order annotation or Ordered interface.